# D3js Select feature from geojson

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, mapping

Learning D3, I am following a lot of tutorials. So far I could create a map of the US with an external json file for all the us-states. However, I like to draw a map with only one of the states (lets say Alabama, which is the 1st feature in the json file).

The code so far:

```
<script>

        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height",h);

        var projection = 3.geo.albersUsa().translate([w/2,h/2]).scale([500]);
        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        d3.json("us-states.json", function(json){

            svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d",path)
                .style("fill", "teal");
        });

   </script>
```

And the sturcture of the .json:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama"},"geometry":
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],...
```

The most primitive way would be, to manually create a new json file with only Alabama in it, but I am sure there are better ways. I think I want to create a new variable with a json object , which I like to use subsequently in the d3.json-function. Something like:

```
var alabama = "us-states.json" (features.id["01"])

d3.json("alabama", function(json){
...
```

but I dont know how to get the information out of the main json file.

Comment: You can filter: `json.features.filter(function(d) { return d.id == "01"; });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select state by index and put everything in array. Like this:

```
.data([topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features[1]])
```

Comment: Ok, I think, this would work, if my source file is a .topojson file. But here I have a .json file from  [link](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_12/us-states.json). If I understand correctly, the formatting is different between both formats.

Comment: Basically, if you like to have only one state, you should pass to data function an array with one object clinked to state you want to have on map.